My caddy file is only adding 1 out of 3 logs endpoint
I have a caddy file and I want to log 2 endpoints into 2 dedicated files and the remaining logs need to be diverted to one common log file. But the caddy is only logging the generic logs and not the 2 dedicated logs. This is my caddy file.
I am looking for a way to log these 2 endpoints and cross-refer it and show in grafana dashbord.
(cors) {
        @origin header Origin {args.0}
        header @origin Access-Control-Allow-Origin "{args.0}"
        header @origin Access-Control-Request-Method POST
}

xyz.be.abc.com:443 {
        header {
                header_up Host {http.request.host}
                header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote}
                header_up X-Forwarded-For {http.request.remote}
                header_up X-Forwarded-Port {http.request.port}
                header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {http.request.scheme}
        }
        # Set this path to your site's directory.
        root * /usr/share/caddy

        @qboWebhook {
                path /backend/quickbooks/*
        }
        log @qboWebhook {
                output file /var/log/caddy/qbo_webhook.log {
                        roll_size 100mb
                        roll_keep 10
                        roll_keep_for 720h
                }
                format json
        }

        @documentsUpload {
                path /backend/documents/directory/*
        }
        log @documentsUpload {
                output file /var/log/caddy/documents_upload.log {
                        roll_size 100mb
                        roll_keep 10
                        roll_keep_for 720h
                }
                format json
        }
        # Default logging for all other requests
        log {
                output file /var/log/caddy/other_requests.log {
                        roll_size 100mb
                        roll_keep 10
                        roll_keep_for 720h
                }
                format json
        }

        # Another common task is to set up a reverse proxy:
        # reverse_proxy localhost:8080

        # Rewrite rule for static files under /queues/static/ and API requests under /queues/api/
        @staticOrApi {
                path /queues/static/*
                path /queues/api/*
        }
        rewrite @staticOrApi /backend{uri}

        # Or serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
        # php_fastcgi localhost:9000
        route /backend/* {
                uri strip_prefix /backend
                reverse_proxy 0.0.0.0:3000
        }
}

